# C# Thread work balancing across different sessions

Tags: c#, multithreading

Assume you have a web server receiving requests. Now each request is connected to a user session. Now the code executed in requests are asynchronous and use parallel execution with multi-threading using e.g. `Task.Run()`, `async await` or `Parallel.ForEach`.

Now what can be observed is that for a certain session a request is triggered that is more heavy than others, uses more parallel task. As a consequence it happens that for a request with a heavy operations a single session can get almost all threads executing for his task. By capturing more tasks other session requests are slowed down. For certain sessions the server seems pretty fast (those that got the threads first) and for others it seems pretty slow, in worst case even unresponsive. What I would like to have is some balance, so that the number of threads being given to the sessions is sort of evenly distributed

How to address the problem?

Options I think that would make sense. Please confirm or tell me why you disagree:

- Work off heavy tasks in dedicated threads where the operations are queued
- Use a custom [TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Most probably there are further options that did not came into my mind. Please help me to find the right wording for this problem. And I would also be very happy if you could guide me to a solution (by conceptually solving or avoiding the problem).

Comment: Can you flesh your question out a bit? What is a request - is it similarly to a web request (short, completes quickly, etc.)?  What's a session?  What's the relationship between request and session?  Are you using the built-in thread pool for your threads?  What is the nature of the work (CPU-bound, IO-bound...)?  Are there big differences between how long each unit of work takes to complete and release its thread?  What makes one request/session more _heavy_ than others? Is there a way to identify those heavy sessions up front?

Comment: Let's assume simple web request, some with heavy operations. Operations are mostly CPU-bound. One request may be more heavy means that the operations in this request have a higher degree of parallelism, and therefore just use more threads. Other operations are waiting for threads to become free, or executing slower with the remaining threads. Theoretically it is possible to identify the heavy ones.

Comment: Many heavy CPU-bound threads on a web server is a difficult thing to overcome.  Remember that a 4-core machine running CPU-bound work runs best when it's running only 4 threads at a time.  If only some of the work is CPU-bound you may want to dispatch work to a separate server, or to a separate thread pool that works on only one or a few dedicated cores.  Sorry... _It depends_

Comment: Next question: How to ask conceptual question that are not in the pattern "This code does not work, why?" on stackoverflow? Or is there another place I should ask the question like this where I don't even yet know how to phrase the problem.

Comment: I tried to [post the question at another place](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/387226/139136) and limit the scope to only ask about the correct terms to describe the problem

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using priorities for tasks submitted from each session. You can have a priority value per session, at the start of the session task submitted will have higher priorities, the more task submitted from a session will get lower priority. This way if a session submits large amount of tasks, a new session can have execution time for its starting tasks because it will have higher priority. (*)

Although this approach does not handle the case if the starting tasks submitted from a session are the heavy ones that will takes large amount of time. (Like Your first option, if You can detect the long running tasks, You could give them lower priority)

There is QueuedTaskScheduler implementation provided by MSFT that You should check.
[source code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=462437453) and [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/09/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/)

(*) Another variation of this approach would be; each priority level can have its own ThreadPool and higher priority levels ThreadPools can contain more threads than lower ones.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible options:

1) Create machine separation such that long running tasks run a separate machine and can be scaled out separately from the web server receiving requests and responding to requests.

2) Process affinity. Rewrite your long running methods to target the same thread ids for high wait times. For example. if you have a 2 core machine. assign cpu 2 only for long running task so that normal requests can still be handled on cpu 1. This will be difficult to do but will work without scaling to new machines.